# Card Deck class for a Poker game

Tags: c++, playing-cards

I have recently finished creating my own `Deck` class for my Poker game. It works the way I want it to, but I would like to know if I can make it better and/or more efficient.

**Deck.h**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include "Card.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Deck
{
private:
static const string RANKS[13], SUITS[4];

int size;
Card cards[52];

void build();

public:
Deck();
~Deck();

void shuffle();
Card drawCard();
int getDeckSize() const {return size;}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Deck&);
};

#endif
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include "Deck.h"

const string Deck::RANKS[13] = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
const string Deck::SUITS[4] = {"H","D","C","S"};

Deck::Deck() : size(0) {build();}

Deck::~Deck() {}

void Deck::build()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    string card;
    bool isSameCard;

    while (size < 52)
    {
        isSameCard = false;

        card = RANKS[rand()%13] + SUITS[rand()%4];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (cards[i].getCard() == card)
                {
                    isSameCard = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if (!isSameCard)
        {
            cards[size].setCard(card);
            size++;
        }
    }
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    build();

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int j = rand() % 52;
        swap(cards[i], cards[j]);
    }
}

Card Deck::drawCard()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR *** DECK EMPTY";
        Card card;
        return card;
    }

    size--;
    return cards[size];
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Deck &aDeck)
{
    for (int i = aDeck.size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << *((aDeck.cards)+i) << endl;

    return out;
}
```

Shuffling a `Deck` object only requires a call to `shuffle()`, so the object does not need to be destroyed for that. The shuffling algorithm works, and I tested this by making a separate check to make sure the deck never contains duplicates.

The driver for the class is in my Poker game itself, but I have tested each function sufficiently. I have both displayed the `Deck` and its size, and have drawn some cards, a few times each run.

I'm paying particular attention to this class because I want to be able to reuse it for future programs. That is one of my biggest interests in this post.

**====== REVISED ======**

**Deck.h**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include "Card.h"

#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Deck
{
private:
    static const int MAX_SIZE = 52;
    static const string RANKS[13];
    static const string SUITS[4];

    int size;
    vector<Card> cards;

public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    Card drawCard();
    void shuffle();
    int getDeckSize() const {return size;}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Deck&);
};

#endif
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include "Deck.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::ostream;
using std::vector;

const string Deck::RANKS[13] = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
const string Deck::SUITS[4] = {"H","D","C","S"};

Deck::Deck() : size(0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Card t;
            t.setCard(RANKS[i] + SUITS[j]);
            cards.push_back(t);
            size++;
        }
    }

    shuffle();
}

Deck::~Deck() {}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    size = MAX_SIZE;
    std::random_shuffle(&cards[0], &cards[MAX_SIZE-1]);
}

Card Deck::drawCard()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR *** DECK EMPTY";
        Card card;
        return card;
    }

    size--;
    return cards[size];
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Deck &aDeck)
{
    for (int i = aDeck.size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        out << aDeck.cards[i] << "\n";

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Never use `using namespace X;` in a header file. If I have to include your header you are polluting the global namespace for me and that can cause all sorts of problems in the code. As this is a potential source for bugs I will never use your header file (until you fix it).

```
using namespace std;
```

Even doing it in a normal *.cpp file is bad as it can cause problems for you. So it is better to fully qualify stuff `std::string` (the extra five letters is not so bad). If you must save those five letters you can bring specific objects into the current scope with `using std::cout;`.

Read all about it here: [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

You are not using anything specific from `iostream`. All you seem to be using is the `std::ostream` but it has its own header file so just include that:

```
#include <ostream>   // rather than <iostream>
```

You re not using time in the header file. So don;t include the  in the header file. Only include the header files that you must include to get it to compile. In this case I would move `ctime` into the Deck.cpp file.

```
#include <ctime>  // Move to Deck.cpp
```

Please one variable per line:

```
static const string RANKS[13], SUITS[4];
```

It makes the code easier to read. There is also one corner case (not hit here) that can hit you so best just not to do this.

If your destructor is not doing anything. Then don't write one:

```
Deck::~Deck() {}
```

Only use srand() **once** in an application.

```
void Deck::build()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

You are not doing yourself any favors with randomness by doing it more than once in an application. By putting it one place (probably just after main()) you know that you will not accidentally get two different pieces of code doing srand() and when debugging is being done you will want to make sure that you use the same sequence so putting srand() where it is easy to find and turn off can be useful.

Your build card could take a long time build the deck (if you get unlucky). An easier way is to put all the cards into the deck then shuffle it.

Good attempt at shuffle. But technically not correct (OK. for the people that complain about the last sentence I am merely quoting (from memory (so in spirit)) Knuth).

To do it correctly.

- Create an empty shuffled deck.

  - You pick a card at random from your deck.
  - Remove card from your deck.
  - Put it on the top of the shuffled deck.
  - If your deck is not empty repeat.

Or you can use the `std::random_shuffle()` algorithm. Which basically does the above algorithm (in place).

In your output operator. You pass the stream but don't use it (I assume that's just a type). Also I would prefer to use "\n" rather than std::endl. std::endl prints a newline then flushes the output. Probably not a performance problem here but in general unless you want to flush the stream prefer "\n".

```
cout << *((aDeck.cards)+i) << endl;  // for some reason you are
                                     // using std::cout

// Use `out` the stream passed in.
```

This is correct.

```
out << *((aDeck.cards)+i) << "\n";
```

But I think this is easier to read:

```
out << aDeck.cards[i] << "\n";
```

I would take this a step further and use a standard algorithm:

```
std::copy(std::begin(aDeck.cards), std::end(aDeck.cards),
          std::ostream_iterator<Card>(out, "\n"));

// Note: If you are using C++03 std::begin() and std::end() are
//       easily replaced with array index and address operations.
```

==========

#### Updated Code

static const integers can be defined and initialized in the class file:

```
// Deck.h
static const int MAX_SIZE = 52;
```

I would not try and do manual memory management:

```
Card *cards;  // New'ed on constructor and delete'd in destructor.
```

This is slightly more complex. Owned RAW pointers (this is one) means you need to implement the rule of three. This means you need to implement (or disable) the copy constructor and assignment operator. Otherwise you open yourself up to problems with double delete.

Note: An "Owned RAW pointer" is a pointer that you are responsible for deleting (this is to distinguish it from pointers that you are not responsible for deleting). Anything you create is usually owned. In most situations in C++ we use either smart pointers or containers to actually own the pointer so that our code can be concerned with business logic.

But a better solution is to use an existing container object:

```
std::vector<Card>  cards;
```

The principle of [separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) means you should use the `std::vector` as the Deck is really an object that deals with business logic it should not also be handling resource management.

The shuffle is better:

```
void Deck::shuffle()
{
    Card *temp = new Card[MAX_SIZE];
    int counter = MAX_SIZE;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        {
            int j = rand() % MAX_SIZE;           // Note: The size is getting smaller
                                                 // each time you remove a card.
                                                 // So you should use  %(MAX_SIZE - i);

            temp[i].setCard(cards[j].getCard());
            swap(cards[j], cards[counter-1]);
            counter--;
        }

    *cards = *temp;  // Note: You have made a call to new.
                     //       As a result you should call delete
                     //       to avoid a memory leak.
                     //
                     //       A better way to do this is:
                     //       std::swap(cards, temp);
                     //       delete [] temp;

                     // Note 2: Note your code here merely swaps
                     //         the first card from the two arrays.

                     // Note 3: You should probably use std::vector<Card>
                     //         for `temp`. It will handle the memory
                     //         management correctly.

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll make the necessary changes and report back if I need more help.  I sort of found out about the namespace thing on my own, but it was never stressed in any of my classes.

Comment: @JamalA: See update at bottom.

Comment: I'm working on the vector now (I'm also very new to that), and I'm getting a "vector subscript out of range" error.  I'm trying to find the problem now.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the in-place [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)? Am I missing something?

Comment: @codesparkle: That's how std::random_shuffle works. But the first step in learning it is to use two stacks. Once you have it working then move on to the in place shuffle. You will notice that he is practically there (he just has not noticed yet).

Comment: @Loki: I have actually read about that shuffle, but I had trouble understanding it.  I was also trying std::random_shuffle, but I just haven't put much effort in getting it working.  Sorting is something I can polish over time, but I am more interested in figuring out vectors.

Comment: As @codesparkle is suggesting you don't actually need to decks. If you move the shuffled cards to one end (and don't include them in subsequent random picks) you achieve the same result. If you look at your code now it actually does this already (assuming you add my fixes). Just remove the swap and references to temp and it should work.

Comment: @JamalA: `std::random_shuffle(&cards[0], &cards[MAX_SIZE])`

Comment: I got it working now!  The vector of objects is starting to make sense, and I'll try to add it to the rest of my program.  The shuffling function was added as well.  I needed to reset the size because my tests didn't otherwise show a full size after a shuffle.

Answer (score 6):

When talking about efficiency, it's useful knowledge that the standard representation of a hand or deck in poker programs is a 64-bit integer.

You assign to each card in a deck one bit, and set it to 1 if the card is present in the deck, or 0 if it's not.

For example like this:

```
23456789TJQKA___23456789TJQKA___23456789TJQKA___23456789TJQKA___ // ranks per bit
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS // colors per bit
1111111111111000111111111111100011111111111110001111111111111000 // full deck
1000000000100000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000001000 // 2cQc9dAhAs
```

It is useful in a way that you can easily access information:

```
bitcount(hand) // number of cards
hand & 0x00ff0000 // all diamonds from a hand
hand & 0x08080808 // all aces from the hand
hand1 & hand2 != 0 // true if two hands share the same card.
```