# Nested Deck class design and implementation

Tags: c++, classes, playing-cards

Previous review of this project:

[Deck and Card classes and member-accessing with one header](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27379/deck-and-card-classes-and-member-accessing-with-one-header)

I'm nearly finished with my deck of cards project, and this time I made changes to hide the `Card` class by nesting it in the `Deck` class.  I'm still getting correct results when displaying the deck.  However, I do now realize that I can no longer maintain `Card` objects outside the class.  Instead, I have to call `Card deal()` with a `Deck` object in order to retrieve a `Card`, and I cannot store that `Card` anywhere.

Does this render my design ineffective for this purpose?  If so, how else can I maintain `Card`s outside the class while still preventing the user from directly constructing a `Card`?  Would a `private` constructor (with `Card` un-nested from `Deck`) be a better option?

**Deck.h**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class Deck
{
private:
    class Card
    {
    private:
        char rank;
        char suit;
        unsigned value;

    public:
        Card::Card() : value(0), rank(' '), suit(' ') {}
        Card::Card(char r, char s, unsigned v) : rank(r), suit(s), value(v) {}
        bool operator<(const Card &rhs) const {return (value < rhs.value);}
        bool operator>(const Card &rhs) const {return (value > rhs.value);}
        bool operator==(const Card &rhs) const {return (suit == rhs.suit);}
        bool operator!=(const Card &rhs) const {return (suit != rhs.suit);}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard)
            {return out << '[' << aCard.rank << aCard.suit << ']';}
    };

    static const unsigned VALUES[13];
    static const char RANKS[13];
    static const char SUITS[4];
    static const unsigned MAX_SIZE = 52;
    std::array<Card, MAX_SIZE> cards;
    int topCardPos;

public:
    Deck();
    void shuffle();
    Card deal();
    unsigned size() const {return topCardPos+1;}
    bool empty() const {return topCardPos == -1;}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Deck &aDeck);
};

#endif
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "Deck.h"

const unsigned Deck::VALUES[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10};
const char Deck::RANKS[13] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};
const char Deck::SUITS[4] = {'H','D','C','S'};

Deck::Deck() : topCardPos(-1)
{
    for (unsigned rank = 0, value = 0; rank, value < 13; ++rank, ++value)
    {
        for (unsigned suit = 0; suit < 4; ++suit)
        {
            topCardPos++;
            cards[topCardPos] = Card(RANKS[rank], SUITS[suit], VALUES[value]);
        }
    }

    shuffle();
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    topCardPos = MAX_SIZE-1;
    std::random_shuffle(&cards.front(), &cards.back()+1);
}

Deck::Card Deck::deal()
{
    if (empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "\nDECK IS EMPTY\n";
        Card blankCard;
        return blankCard;
    }

    topCardPos--;
    return cards[topCardPos+1];
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Deck &aDeck)
{
    for (unsigned iter = aDeck.size(); iter--> 0;)
    {
        out << "\n" << aDeck.cards[iter];
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I understand your question, you want `Card` to be publicly available, yet only `Deck` should be able to construct a `Card`. One way to achieve this is to make the `Card()`  constructor private and a `friend` of `Deck`:

```
class Deck;

class Card {
    Card() {}
    friend class Deck;
public:
    // ...
};

class Deck {
    Card card;                     // ok
public:
    Card createCard() {            // ok
        return Card();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deck deck;
    Card card = deck.createCard();

    Card doesntWork;               // error! Attempt to access private member
}
```

A somewhat cleaner solution would be to have only `createCard()` as `friend` of `Card`. In that case, however, you will have to dynamically allocate the `Card` (and return a pointer to it), because of mutual dependencies.

(The reason for this is that `Card` needs the definition, and not just declaration, of `Deck` to declare one of the `Deck` functions a friend. At the same time, `Deck::createCard()` needs the definition of `Card` to be able to return a `Card` by value. If you return a pointer, however, you only need the declaration.)

---

**Other comments:**

**1:** Consider giving ranks, suits and values distinct and unique types. For example using `enum`. Make use of the type system to enlist the compiler's aid -- by doing this you will be notified if you accidentally switch types somewhere.

**2:** I would change

```
for (unsigned iter = aDeck.size(); iter--> 0;)
```

to the more traditional

```
for (int i = aDeck.size() - 1; i > -1; --i)
```

The latter is more readable and clear about what is going on. The former is vulnerable to be *incorrected*, i.e. refactored to the (incorrect)

```
for (unsigned iter = aDeck.size(); iter > 0; --iter)
```

**3:** Don't call a variable `iter` when it's a counter and not an iterator.

**4:** Initializer list ordering should be the same as the variables are declared in the class. By doing this, you avoid ever risking dependency problems. (Variables are always initialized in the order they are declared in the class, *not* the order they appear in initializer lists.)

**5:** [Reorder your `#includes` in the implementation file.](http://blog.knatten.org/2010/07/01/the-order-of-include-directives-matter/)

**Update**

**6:** Your card generation/constructor is error-prone. Apart from introducing type safety, I would recommend generating `value` based on `rank`, for example through a function and an `std::map`.

Comment: Yes!  That's my ideal `main()` right there. :-) I'll try to work out these changes.

Comment: I've made the changes (in addition to using `std::vector` instead of `std::array`), and my results are to my satisfaction.  Many thanks!  I have kept `deal()` intact, though.  In that function, is there a better way to handle an empty deck (internally), or is that good enough?  In its current form, I'll have to keep my default constructor.

Comment: @Jamal: Happy to help! You can keep it the way it is, you could reshuffle the deck and deal again or you could throw an exception. What is "best" depends on the situation. While considering this, I noticed another issue; see the updated post. By the way, consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: Since I'm using `std::vector` now, I put in more code to allow the `shuffle()` to work with it.  I'm now just trying to figure out how to do the `enum`/`std::map` idea.  Since the ranks' values depends on the specific game, I'll need to be able to change them easily.  Oh yeah, sorry about that.  I considered waiting for any additional answers, but this one did answer my question.

Comment: @Jamal: An object-oriented sketch to point you in the right direction: http://codepad.org/YRi4rgLl. If using C++11, you could instead bind the correct assignment function to a `std::function`, for example.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at the link since I haven't heard of `std::function` before.

Comment: I put that code into a header file, and it doesn't compile.  I can't figure out how to use it anyway (I'm barely familiar with OOP), so I'll stay with what I have for now.

Comment: I got it working with an `std::map`, which I put in a header file.  The suits is now in a string, so all of the iterating for both containers is done via the `auto` method.